# Is there a C# equivalent for the MATLAB `imagesc()` function, or the python `plt.imshow()`? i.e., show an image on a colorscale with explicit min/max

Tags: python, c#, .net, image, opencv

We are translating some of our Python code from research into C# code for production. [OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) has been immensely helpful in this respect, and we've also used [C# Jupyter Notebooks](https://ewinnington.github.io/posts/jupyter-tips-csharp) to validate features prior to pulling into main.

Part of the bottleneck our been the inability to graph/present/visualize scientific, single-channel image data in the intermediate stages of processing, as we would currently do with `plt.imshow()` in Python or `imagesc` in MATLAB. Are there any good ways to do this scaling and presentation in C#, ideally for inclusion in a C# notebook file?

Comment: There is nothing built into the c# language to do that. You'd need to find a 3rd party library yourself, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: [`Cv2.ApplyColorMap`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/03e9199a-f6e5-b4ee-67d2-30eae20cc8d4.htm)...?

Comment: @gunr2171 I've added the `opencv` and `.net` tags (which are replacing the old `opencvsharp` tag), and now it's on-topic :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help all. As far as I can tell @canton7, Cv2.ApplyColorMap does not allow specification of explicit min, max of the colorbar. It would also be nice to show the colorbar alongside the image, similar to `plt.imshow(); plt.colorbar();`

Comment: @gunr2171 Support for third-party libraries is very much on-topic. I think you've mis-understood the "No recommendations for third-party libraries" rule, which says we're not supposed to *recommend* third-party libraries, i.e. if someone asks "What's a good library to do X". That's not the same as providing support for a specific, identified library.

Comment: @SamJett It's pretty trivial to do, though: just scale the range you're interested between the min and max you want. It's also pretty trivial to create a new Mat containing your image and the color bar if you want, it will take a couple of lines of code